# Why does it work in jsfidde but not on my browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please check out this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xNEZH/2/

It works fine in my jsfiddle

[BOX APPEARS WHEN TEXT IS INPUTTED IN INPUT]

but doesn't work on my browsers BUT I am using the latest versions of safari, firefox and chrome.

What is the matter?

HTML / JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
(function watchInputForChanges(){
    var hasInput = $('.input1').val() != "";
    $('.box')[hasInput ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    setTimeout(watchInputForChanges, 100);
})();
});
</script>

<link href="cloud.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>

<div class="center1">
<form>
<input type="text" class="input1" autofocus="focus"  />
</form>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="center1">
<div class="box">f</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your code also wrapped in a DOM ready as it is on jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just posted the code above for you

Comment: Looks like it isn't wrapped in a DOM ready. If you use jQuery (which I would obviously assume as you use it within your code, but at least in the code you provided, it is not embedded), you can use the answer provided by AbstractDownvoteFactor. If you don't have jQuery, then you need to embed it, or change your code and execute it after the element has been created.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to add this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //function name does not exist outside this scope
    (function watchInputForChanges(){
        var hasInput = $('.input1').val() != "";
        $('.box')[hasInput ? 'show' : 'hide']();
        setTimeout(watchInputForChanges, 100);
    })();
});
```

---

**Drav Sloan** pointed out that you are missing the jQuery include as well

Comment: Hi I added this but still its not working, what am i doing wrong? Please check the code I just posted in the question above!

Comment: put your script tag at the bottom of the page

Comment: That won't help, I don't think; it's already in a "ready" handler.

Comment: You also need to load jquery with `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js></script>` (or to your local copy of jquery)

Comment: @Pointy, I was talking about his updated posted code. But you are correct that even that should make a difference.

Comment: Agree with Drag, check that you have jquery loaded.

Comment: I am new to this, I have made a separate file and put the javascript code above in it. What do I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not answering the direct question (simply "why doesn't this work outside of fiddle?") but I can't resist: not sure why you're polling for changes; you can bind a listener to the element. For example (in the document ready function...)

In the HTML itself:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script> <!--or wherever your script source is!!-->
```

Then if you're putting your scripts into tags on the same page (instead of external):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        (function() {
            $input = $('.input1');
            $box = $('.box');
            $input.on('keypress input paste', function() {
                if ($box.not(':visible') && $input.val() != "") {
                    $box.show();
                } else {
                    $box.hide();
                }
            });
        })();
    });
</script>
```

Catches manual entry or pasted entry.

http://jsfiddle.net/xNEZH/12/

Comment: Thanks, it does it in jsfiddle but not one my browser. Do i need to download a jsquery plugin? ifso what am i looking for?

Comment: James, it's like the other commenters and respondents have already said: you need to include jQuery before anything else (your original sample was jQuery-based code, so we mainly assumed you were already doing that), and then you need to wrap it in a document ready function as per IAbstractDVF's answer.

Comment: Sorry, the jquery code was given to me in my previous question. I downloaded the above link but it still doesn't work. I updated my code above too!

Comment: Nobody can help you much more than that. The code samples all work. You're not loading jQuery into your page properly is my guess.