# jQuery Effects work in jsfiddle but not in offline/online

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have been having this problem for about 4 months now i gave up at first but now i have to solve it am trying to do a zoom in effect on hover and i did all the code and it works properly, but when  i copy it and paste it in the editor or like the code it self it doesn't work i tried Firefox (latest version) and Google chrome(also latest version) but still no effect happens nothing and also i tried using Google's cdm and also tried downloading the jQuery from the website itself nothing worked out please help me as i am just a beginner in coding thank you

My HTML :

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Random Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"; href="Stylesheet.css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="RandomPage.png">

    <p style="margin-right:220px; margin-top:20px; float:right; font-size:22px; font-family:century gothic; id="nav2" ">I <a id="nav" href="">HOME</a> I <a id="nav" href="">Apple</a> I <a id="nav" href="">Android</a> I <a id="nav" href="">Gaming</a> I <a id="nav" href="">Random Tech</a> I <a id="nav" href="">About Us</a> I </p>

    <div id="menu">
        <img style=" margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px; border-radius:4px; " src="RandomGaming.png" class="resizableImage">
         <img style=" margin-top:10px; border-radius:4px;" src="RandomFashion.png" class="resizableImage">
    </div>
</body>
```

my script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('.resizableImage').mouseenter(function() {
$(this).stop().animate({ width: "+=10%", height: "+=10%" });
});

$('.resizableImage').mouseleave(function() {
var x = $(this).attr('width'),
    y = $(this).attr('height');

$(this).stop().animate({ width: x, height: y });
});
});
```

Thank You In Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does it work in jsfidde but not on my browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234545/why-does-it-work-in-jsfidde-but-not-on-my-browser)

Comment: There's not enough information here about your site to be able to help. I'd take a wild guess that it's either 1) file path/url issues, 2) load order, or 3) your editor stripping code.

Comment: it looks like you are not calling the jquery library in your <head>

Comment: Just a side note, your HTML is invalid, `id`'s need to be unique, you have used the id `nav` more than once. You never closed the `style` attribute in the `p` tag and `img` are self-closing tags.

Comment: On your site, and in Developer tools (Chrome or Firebug), type this in the console and let me know what version shows up: $.fn.jquery

Comment: not one script tag in html shown, have to incldue scripts for them to load

Comment: @YazTheGreat, if one of the answers helped you, you should mark it as "ACCEPTED", otherwise you may have a difficult time getting more questions answered.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @MikeBarwick but nothing helped for now, um i did include the jQuery Libary but still nothing happened and what do you mean by load order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the jquery library, and it has to be the first thing you add.

Paste this `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your head tag, and make sure it's the FIRST script there.

Comment: I know that, but I recommend keeping all libraries, etc. in one place - at the top. Meh, whatever, I added it

Comment: Recommend? You're misinformed. It's more efficient and allows your pages to load faster if JS scripts are included before your closing <body /> tag above the functions..

Comment: I Added it but still nothing happens

Comment: Oh My God Sir, It worked, But now it just keeps zooming in when i hover the mouse on it and when i move the mouse out it doesn't go back to its original size

Answer (score 0):

Your sample HTML is not including jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Put the follwoing script below the  script in your head. So liek this:

```
<head>
    <title>Random Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"; href="Stylesheet.css" media="all">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include future js scripts here -->
</head>
```

Then JUST before your closing `</body>` tag, add the jQuery code, like so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  

    $('.resizableImage').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ width: "+=10%", height: "+=10%" });
    });

    $('.resizableImage').mouseleave(function() {
        var x = $(this).attr('width'),
        y = $(this).attr('height');

        $(this).stop().animate({ width: x, height: y });
    });

});
</script>
```

**Note:** It's more efficient and allows your pages to load faster if your JS scripts are included before your closing  tag above the functions..but for simplicity sake, I included it in the `<head>`, which is not bad either.

Comment: Can you explain why one has to be in the `head` and the other at the end of `body`?

Comment: Both would work. However, the browser stops rendering the page until each block of JavaScript has been executed. For small JavaScript blocks, this isn't a big problem. However, for large libraries, page load time could be substantially increased.

Comment: Yes true, therefor, especially the libraries should be added just before the closing `body` tag and not in the head.

Comment: Absolutely! See my "Note" in my answer. ;)

Comment: That said, typically I'll just have a few base scripts, such as jQuery in my header. Then render others before my body tag. The ones I'll always use go in the header so I'm not repeating code in my views, etc.

Comment: The browser also has to include all the script blocks you add in the header (such as the jQuery library). That makes the page rendering take longer as well.

Comment: Yes, but that's going to happen anyways. jQuery scripts are often cached in users browsers - so jQuery hardly plays a role in slowing down pages from loading. It's typically the larger "custom" scripts that should be executed once all the HTML and CSS has loaded, etc.

Comment: Thanks, But tried it nothing happened still, maybe there is something wrong in the code, or would it be possible if its a problem for the computer itself?

Comment: I think the problem is you man, no offence. Google and find a few basic starter tutorial on how to built your first website. You need to grasp the basics, which you're lacking.